# Replace Specific Index Positions in a String

Tags: javascript

I have a String of todays date, '2022-01-04'. I am trying to create a new string that would represent the first day of the month, '2022-01-01'.

Everything I have found online as it relates to replacing in a string is all about replacing a specific letter or word or something like that. I was to specifically change the last 2 index positions of the string to '01'.

I also could not use the replace '04' since my hopes is to get this to work on any day of any month.

Comment: While you can surely do this with indices, i'd prefer regex - makes it imho more readable in this case. However, for both, i'd expect you to read a bit, and make an attempt.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

I would try creating a new `Date` object first:

```js
const date = new Date(Date.parse('2022-01-04'));
```

Once you have that, creating the first of the month is simple:

```js
const firstOfMonthDate = new Date(date);
firstOfMonthDate.setDate(0); // Set day to first of month
```

Then you can get a `String` directly from the definitively set date:

```js
const firstOfMonthDateAsString = firstOfMonthDate.toISOString().slice(0, 10); // 2022-01-01
```